# Portable Usenet news reader/client

Tags: windows, software-rec, usenet, newsreader

I'm looking for a Usenet newsgroup reader/client for Windows that saves everything to its own directory.

I'm aiming at a dedicated newsreader only. No "mixed" programs like Outlook, Thunderbird or the like which usually don't have as many features that specialized newsreaders do.

**Wanted features:** watch thread, keep thread, ignore thread/subthread, easy and distinctive reply organisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Forté Agent](http://www.forteinc.com) might do what you want.  When I used it, a previous version, it didn't use the registry at all, but saved everything into its data directory.

Comment: Finally, an usenet professional ;) Agent is actually what I'm using at the moment (been using it since ver 1.0 !),but I've never managed to work portably. He would always complain about either missing reg. entries, or data files (version 5.0 doesn't save data files in its own directory, but in the docs. and settings one ...)

Comment: There's a recent discussion about this in alt.usenet.offline-reader.forte-agent:
http://groups.google.com/group/alt.usenet.offline-reader.forte-agent/msg/c2c47f54fc885afb

Answer (score 2):

Give [**Pan**](http://pan.rebelbase.com/) a try, you can grab it as a zip to extract anywhere. Available for Linux and Windows.

There is also [**FastTrackNews**](http://www.fasttracknews.com/).

Comment: Ja. Danke Johannes. I always forget people nowadays call rss feeds "news".

Comment: well that changes things a bit, answer updated.

Comment: Not really portable, since it requires GTK which is very rare on Windows. And AFAIS it can't be made portable, but must be installed.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/GTK%20Portable/

Comment: Just tried both of them. Pan is not that bad, but the other one can hardly be called a reader. It's missing even the most basic features.

Comment: I mean, it's good for what it's designed for, but that is not news reading.

Comment: +1 for Pan. It's a good NNTP client.

Answer (score 0):

Along with John T's suggestions, also found this one:

[MesNews](http://www.mesnews.net/gb/)

but still waiting for other suggestions.